# Gnome partially stops responding to mouse, keyboard

Tags: linux, rhel, gnome, mouse

I'm running **RHEL** Workstation 7.6.  Ever since I set it up in November, I've had an ongoing issue with my system (and this is my daily desktop).

- On occasion, I'm unable to click on anything. I can alt-tab, and I can type in windows.  The mouse will move but clicking does nothing.
- The keyboard mostly works but, say in a terminal window, I hold down the Alt key.  The menu (File, Edit, View...) lights up but if I then hit Alt-F, to open the File menu, nothing happens.
- Sometimes I can click on tabs in Firefox and they change - but I can't actually bring Firefox into the foreground, nor click the X to close it.
- If I go to TTY2 (Ctrl-Aalt-F2) and then back to TTY1, it fixes it.  Until the next time.  Sometimes the fix only lasts for seconds but, if I keep trying, it will be okay for a long time - many minutes or hours.

Some log entries while it's acting up.  The first one occurs any time I click on a gnome-shell window while it's broken:

```
Feb 22 08:16:33 mybox gnome-shell[6845]: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed

Feb 22 08:17:38 mybox autokey-gtk.desktop[7488]: X protocol error:
Feb 22 08:17:38 mybox autokey-gtk.desktop[7488]: <class 'Xlib.error.BadWindow'>: code = 3, resource_id = Xlib.xobject.resource.Resource(0x00e11c6b), sequence_number = 46319, major_opcode = 33, minor_opcode = 0

Feb 22 08:17:50 mybox gnome-shell[6845]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
```

Comment: I'm in same situation, I ususlly work-around by logging of then back on (not shutting down the machine). After doing so, mouse became responsive again

Comment: @DDS - try the ctrl-alt-f2, ctrl-alt-f1 trick (assuming your GUI is on tty1).  A lot easier than logging out.

Comment: Have a similar problem when using `tigervncserver` running Gnome 3.22.2. Once every 20 connects to the vncserver my keyboard & mouse inputs will be ignored. Keyboard typing ends in a single terminal. Mouse cursor moves but clicks are ignored. ctrl-alt-f1 and ctrl-alt-f2 have no effect (not sure what "got to TTY2" means).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problems of authorizations, try to install Polkit (PolicyKit Authentication Agent API) is a framework that provides an authorization API used by privileged programs (also called mechanisms) offering services to unprivileged programs (also called subjects). The following are details on the changes PolicyKit, or its system name polkit, has undergone.

More Info about Polkit in RHEL visit https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/policykit

I hope that will solve your Problem. Good Luck

Comment: polkit is already installed.  I installed polkit-gnome also - but the issue still recurs.